# How to get POSTDATA from webbrowser object in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, beforenavigate2

I understand in previous versions of VB the webbrowser object had a beforenavigate2 event that provided access to the postdata of the webbrowser.

I've searched and searched and I think that event was disabled for visual studio 2010.

Any thoughts on how I could grab postdata from the webbrowser object?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was struggling with the same question and now thought of sharing the answer here. Credits for this answer goes to [luchosrock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858578/luchosrock) since he was the one that teached it to me.

If you have an instance of the [System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) object named, say, **browser**, you can implement your own handler to control the [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event (that is somehow equivalent to BeforeNavigate2) and use the [System.Net.WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and [System.Net.WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) objects from within it:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Windows.Forms
'[...]
Private Sub browser_Navigating(sender As Object, _ 
                               e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) _ 
                           Handles browser.Navigating

    Dim req As WebRequest
    Dim res As WebResponse
    Dim postDataStream As Stream
    Dim WebResponse As String = ""
    '[...]
    Try
        req = WebRequest.Create(e.Url.ToString)
        req.Method = "POST"
        res = req.GetResponse
        postDataStream = res.GetResponseStream
        Dim webStreamReader As New StreamReader(postDataStream)
        While webStreamReader.Peek >= 0
            WebResponse = webStreamReader.ReadToEnd
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Exception control code here
    End Try
    '[...]
End Sub
```

It is not the same as accessing directly the **PostData** object from within the **BeforeNavigating2** event, but is a nice alternative, I think.

If this answer doesn't satisfices you, there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231774/1541625) in another question in which a method is explained to handle directly the old **BeforeNavigate2** event.