# How to capture the WebBrowser control close event?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a `WebBrowser` control in a WPF application. The browser control is in a grid and when the `WebBrowser` control renders some webpages, in one of the pages there is popup alert box from the webpage, and when the user taps on the popup the `WebBrowser` control seems to be closed. I need to capture this close event and take some action.

I already tried subscribing to the unload event but it does not seem to fire. Is there any way to get this event captured?

Answer (score 0):

There is [WindowClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event on the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX control for that. I haven't tried it myself, but I think it should work.

Here's a [full-fledged sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20902928/1768303) showing how handle the "underlying" `WebBrowser` events like that. It's for WPF, but it can be easily adapter for WinForms (using `WebBrowser.ActiveXInstance`).